# IE not recognizing post data using LoadVars from flash inside a frameset

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, frames

This code is being run from a frameset in IE8. When the new window is opened, the form data is not being recognized. It appears that the http header, "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", is not being passed into IE and this is causing the post data not to be processed. The data is there, IE is just doing nothing with it.

This code works fine in FF and Chrome, and in fact the correct headers are passed in FF and Chrome. Has anyone else run into this problem?

NOTE: The new page is on a different site, but i don't know why that would cause a problem with a POST and not a GET.

Flash code:

```
varSender = new LoadVars();
varSender.title = _parent.tCourseTitle;
varSender.notes = input_txt.text;
varSender.send("http://example.com/notes/print.cfm", "_blank", "POST");
```

I have tried adding the header to the send request, but that has no effect at all. The contenttype header is still missing and it still works everywhere but IE.

My current work around is to use a GET instead of a post, but that's ugly and it limits us in the size of data we can pass but for now at least it works.

Comment: I have the same problem and sone other people also [Link on board.flashkit.com](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=629879) or [Link on w3schools.invisionzone.com](http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=25602) but there is no solution even if the posts are quite old

Answer (score 1):

i found if the 'problem' actionscript3 code compiled with flash cs4, there will be no problem.